# Wordpress: how to hook get_the_post_thumbnail_url() function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I'm new to Wordpress. What I am trying to do is to hook the `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` and return slightly different URL. I know that I can use WP `add_action()` for hooking. If I write my function and return required string how can I make sure that the `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` will return my customized code?

Comment: Do you need to hook into it or could you create your own version of the function like: my_get_the_post_thumbnail_url() which passes it's args onto the original function, does its modifications there and returns the modifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**get_the_post_thumbnail_url** in **wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php** has no hooks or actions, it's defined as follows:

```
function get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post = null, $size = 'post-thumbnail' ) {
  $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post );
  if ( ! $post_thumbnail_id ) {
    return false;
  }
  return wp_get_attachment_image_url( $post_thumbnail_id, $size );
}
```

If you follow the **wp_get_attachment_image_url** function you find it uses the **wp_get_attachment_image_src** function which DOES apply filters so you are able to create a filter for it using `wp_get_attachment_image_src`

That will be your only way to interact with that function, albeit a little further up the functionality tree.

Usage instructions are as follows:

```
/**
     * Filters the image src result.
     *
     * @since 4.3.0
     *
     * @param array|false  $image         Either array with src, width & height, icon src, or false.
     * @param int          $attachment_id Image attachment ID.
     * @param string|array $size          Size of image. Image size or array of width and height values
     *                                    (in that order). Default 'thumbnail'.
     * @param bool         $icon          Whether the image should be treated as an icon. Default false.
     */
    apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon );
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see two different ways to achieve this.

## Solution 1 (file from the media library)

There is a filter that you can use to override (or provide a default value) for the `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` function.

During the process, the function will call `get_post_meta()` which will eventually call the filter `get_{$meta_type}_metadata`.

What you can do is hook this filter with something like :

```php
add_filter( 'get_post_metadata', function ( $metadata, int $object_id, string $meta_key, bool $single, string $meta_type ) {
    // @todo fetch a predefined file ID (this must be an existing file from the media library).

    return $metadata;
}, 10, );
```

The drawback form this method is that you cannot provide some random URL, but you need to use an existing file from the media library.

## Solution 2 (any custom URL)

In order to provide a fully customizable URL for your post thumbnail, you will need to hook 3 different functions.

```php
add_filter( 'has_post_thumbnail', 'so52332168_hasPostThumbnail', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'get_post_metadata', 'so52332168_getPostThumbnailFileId', 10, 4 );
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'so52332168_getPostThumbnailSrc', 10, 4 );

/**
 * Use any way you want to determine if your post should have a custom thumbnail URL.
 *
 * @param $has_thumbnail
 * @param $post_id
 * @param $thumbnail_id
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function so52332168_hasPostThumbnail( $has_thumbnail, $post_id, $thumbnail_id ) {
    if ( ! $has_thumbnail ) {
        // @todo check if the $post_id match any rule to get a custom thumbnail.
        // if so, return true here

        return true;
    }
    
    return $has_thumbnail;
}

/**
 * Force override the thumbnail URL.
 *
 * @param $value
 * @param $object_id
 * @param $meta_key
 * @param $single
 *
 * @return int
 */
function so52332168_getPostThumbnailFileId( $value, $object_id, $meta_key, $single ) {
    if ( '_thumbnail_id' === $meta_key ) {
        // @todo check if the current $object_id should get a custom thumbnail (probably the same check as above)
            global $customPostThumbnailUrl;
            $customPostThumbnailUrl = 'https://placekitten.com/300/300';

            // return the fake thumbnail id -> this should absolutely never match an actual file id
            return PHP_INT_MAX;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $value;
}

/**
 * Eventually return the URL that we "calculate" for the post.
 *
 * @param $image
 * @param $attachment_id
 * @param $size
 * @param $icon
 *
 * @return array
 */
function so52332168_getPostThumbnailSrc( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ) {
    global $customPostThumbnailUrl;

    // check that the attachment id is the one we returned previously
    if ( (PHP_INT_MAX === $attachment_id) && $customPostThumbnailUrl ) {
        // return our custom image URL
        return [ $customPostThumbnailUrl ];
    }
    
    return $image;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to filter the URLs of the thumbnail images in the admin pages, like the Media page? Your code here considers the thumbnail of a post, not an attachment. I tried to filter the thumbnail URL using the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` hook, but it didn't work, I can't even catch that with the debugger (the hook seems not triggered), and the URL is being replaced with the original URL at the end. How to use your solution with the admin pages thumbnails? Otherwise, is there any other hook that may filter the thumbnail URL?